# How do I create MySQL query to get result from different year?

Tags: mysql

This is my original query:

```
SELECT *
FROM c60_hrd.hrclhf
WHERE hrch_clm_mth >= '1' AND hrch_clm_mth <= '2'
  and hrch_clm_year >= '2017' AND hrch_clm_year <= '2017'
ORDER BY hrch_clm_no;
```

It works fine. However, it doesn't work if I want to get a result for a different year, for example, from year 2016 to 2017. So I made the adjustment to that query:

```
SELECT *
FROM c60_hrd.hrclhf
WHERE (hrch_clm_mth >= '12' AND hrch_clm_year >= '2016') 
   OR (hrch_clm_mth <= '2' and hrch_clm_year <= '2017')
ORDER BY hrch_clm_no;
```

It works fine to get the result for the different year. But when I change to that query, I get wrong results if I want to query within the same year. For example, from month 2 to 3 and year 2017. It displays a record from month 1 to 3 which I don't want. It supposedly displays a record from month 2 and 3 only.

Kindly help me.

Comment: It would be quite simple if your dates were held as DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP and not as seperate columns for Month and Year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', hrch_clm_year, hrch_clm_mth,'1'),'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-03-01'
```

If you want to use year and month components separately,  then you can do following:

```
SELECT *
FROM c60_hrd.hrclhf
WHERE (hrch_clm_mth + 12*hrch_clm_year) BETWEEN (@StartMonth + 12*@StartYear) AND  (@FinishMonth + 12*@FinishYear)
ORDER BY hrch_clm_no;
```

Comment: thank god! it works like a charm. Thank you so much :)